# Getting system env in c++ from windows

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

I try to fetch some system env in windows from my C++ application. I tried getenv and GetEnvironmentVariable but both stuck. A program compiles but when I run it I see blinking pointer for some time, nothing displays and then program crash with message:

RUN FAILED (exit value -1 073 741 819, total time: 10s)

I tried a lot of examples from the net and all of them give the same result. Some examples I tried:

```
char l_strSingleVal[20];
GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", l_strSingleVal,20);
printf("VariableName: %s\n",l_strSingleVal);
```

or:

```
std::string string_variable;
const std::string MY_VAR = "PATH";

char const* temp = std::getenv(MY_VAR.c_str());
if(temp != NULL)
{
    string_variable = std::string(temp);            
}
```

Comment: -1073... is probably because you haven't got a "return 0" at the end of your `main`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: How's that? Maybe the compiler is broken...

Comment: Ah, no, it's a memory violation, 0xc0000005 error code. I expect it's in some code that hasn't been posted here... At least if the second version actually gives this behaviour.

Comment: I have return 0 at the end of main. I use MinGW. The project is a bit bigger but I believe I posted important parts - when I replace them with simple std::cout<<"test" everything works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behviour:

From GetEnvironmentVariable spec (l_strSingleVal is equivalent to lpBuffer): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx

> If lpBuffer is not large enough to hold the data, the return value is
>   the buffer size, in characters, required to hold the string and its
>   terminating null character and the contents of lpBuffer are undefined.

Accessing lpBuffer in your case is UB. A 20 character buffer for PATH is way too small. You need to check the return value of `GetEnvironmentVariable` (which in your case will be telling you the size of the buffer required for successful invocation).

Comment: I gave 20000 instead of 20 and the result is the same... :/

Comment: Possibly more UB in another place. Would you mind posting the entire function? Btw, that approach is crude: you ought to allocate exactly the space you need; using the return of an initial invocation of GetEnvironmentVariable.

Comment: I just need to get the value of APPDATA env - I don't know how big it will be... and this is entire function - I just try to get through getting this var and display it. Once it's done I can continue with the app...

Answer (score 2):

Tried C standard library function `getenv`? It works for me on my Windows PC.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char * src = getenv("PATH");
 if (src)
  printf("value of PATH is: %s", src);
 else 
  printf("empty or not defined");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and I get the same problem.